# 'mongoexport' not working when trying to run the command in a Python script

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoexport

My requirement is to execute the 'mongoexport' command to get the data in mongo db into a csv and then compare it against another csv to identify any exceptions/discrepancies. I am trying to implement this using python 3.6 but am getting "'mongoexport' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file" error.

Below is my code snippet:

```
import os
import pymongo as mng
import subprocess


connected = False

#Open DB connection
try:
    connection = mng.MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
    db = connection['foo']
    print("I am connected to Mongo DB")
    connected = True
except:
    print("I am not able to connect to Mongo DB")

tgt_count = db.restaurants.count()
path = subprocess.call("dir",shell=True)
subprocess.call("mongoexport --db foo --collection restaurants --type=csv --fieldFile D:/my_mongo/fldlist.txt --out D:/my_mongo/outfile.csv", shell=True)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSlWm.png)

Note: I am getting this while trying to run in Pycharm IDE.

You can see I have confirmed the location from which the command is running to (path = subprocess.call("dir",shell=True)). After ensuring the dir location I manually ran the same mongoexport command in the Windows command prompt and it worked fine - so the environment variable not being updated properly should not be the issue. Also the call function seems to work as well - Any pointers to what I am doing wrong/missing would be of great help...Please

Comment: Are you passing your arguments via a list?

Answer (score 3):

Put `dir` in single quotes. Also if you are using the arguments in list form, then remove `shell=true`. If they are in string form, you can add `shell=true`

```
import os
import pymongo as mng
import subprocess


connected = False

#Open DB connection
try:
    connection = mng.MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
    db = connection['foo']
    print("I am connected to Mongo DB")
    connected = True
except:
    print("I am not able to connect to Mongo DB")

tgt_count = db.restaurants.count()
path = subprocess.call('dir',shell=True)
subprocess.call("mongoexport --db foo --collection restaurants --type=csv --fieldFile D:/my_mongo/fldlist.txt --out D:/my_mongo/outfile.csv")
```

Comment: My dir command is working fine - my problem is that the mongoexport does not work. I have tried running it will single quotes - no luck

Comment: and if you run the full path in the subprocess.call?

Comment: I figured this out finally... My IDE was not picking up my environment variable updates. I just restarted the IDE and it worked fine. Thanks @gerhard-barnard for looking into this - appreciate your time.